# Increasing Differentiable Functions

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $I$ is an interval and $f : I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a differentiable function. If $f'(x) > 0$ for all $x \in I$, show that $f$ is strictly increasing.

I have so far that if $f'(x) > 0$, then $f(x) > f(c)$ where $c$ is some constant. Is this a correct starting place and if so where do I go from here?

Comment: I've formatted your question. To find out how to do it yourself see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/)

Answer (score 1):

If $x,y\in I$ and $x<y$, then apply the mean value theorem to $f$ on the interval $[x,y]$. You discover that there's a $c\in (x,y)$ such that:

$0<f'(c)=\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}$.

What does that tell you about $f(y)-f(x)$?

I hope this helps!

Comment: it tells you that the difference in y values is positive which implies that the function is increasing, correct?

Comment: @user72195 Yes, seems correct to me!